# Porting from windows to android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl-2

I am struggling with porting a windows application to android. I use **SDL** and **C++**.
In my Player.cpp class I have a function :

```
SDL_Rect Player::getPlayerPos()
{
    return _pos;
}
```

Now in main I have a player object :

```
Player myPlayer;
```

**1ST WAY** :When I try to render it ... I get a weird error when running ndk-build(but on VS2013 everything works fine).

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, playerTexture, NULL, &myPlayer.getPlayerPos());
```

[Errors I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEgrJ.png)

**2ND WAY** : Also I tried putting it in another SDL_Rect variable :

```
SDL_Rect temporary;
temporary = player.getPlayerPos();
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, playerTexture, NULL, &temporary);
```

...still get errors...

[Errors I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPU3x.png)

**3RD WAY** : I alse tried another way : 
Now I changed the function.

```
void Player::getPlayerPos(SDL_Rect& rect)
{
    rect = _pos;
}
```

and main

```
SDL_Rect temporary;
myPlayer.getPlayerPos(temporary);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, playerTexture, NULL, &temporary);
```

..still errors..(the same errors as 2nd way)

**IMPORTANT** : All the errors I got are just when I build with ndk-build. With VS2013 everything works

Why do I keep getting weird errors when I try to port code to android?
Do you have any useful advice for this problem/ do you know a a tutorial or some websites that can help me with porting and writing portable code?

***Thank you very much in advance :)***

Comment: You could try reading the errors.  I know that isn't the way it's done on Windows, but it actually helps on Android.

Comment: Also, since copying text from a Windows command window works just fine, there's no reason to post compiler messages in the form of screenshots.

Comment: @Michael I will do so next time..but how do others do it? Many have this problem but nobody gives an answer ..